# How to format array data in a table with specified number of column?

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I tried to put check box array data into table with 3 columns.

I have an array named `$a` which contains 26 data, from A to Z.

Then I have another array named `$b` which contains some data.

I want to create a 3-columns table with 26 check boxes with the data in array `$a`.

if the data is contained in `$b`, its checkbox will be checked otherwise it's unchecked.

The following is my code. I have no idea how to format the loop so the checkboxes and table will show correctly. Please help.

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<?php

$a = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","s","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z");
$b = array("A","C","G","L","O","P","R","X","Z");
$a_size=count($a);

$tr=$a_size/3;
$reminder=$a_size%3;

if ($reminder!=0)
{
$tr+=1;
}

for($i=0;$i<$tr;$i++)
{
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($b AS $c)
{
    for($j=0;$j<3;$j++)
    {
        if(in_array($c,$b)) 
        {
            echo "<td><input name=\"system[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$c\" CHECKED> $c </td>";
        } 
        else
        {
            echo "<td><input name=\"system[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$c\"> $c </td>";
        }
    }
}   
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>                                                
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're making it a little overcomplicated! Here's how I would approach this situation:

```
<?php
    $a = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z");
    $b = array("A","C","G","L","O","P","R","X","Z");
?>
<table>
    <?php foreach ($a as $k => $v) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $v; ?></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="system[]" value="<?php echo $v; ?>" <?php if (in_array($v, $b)) echo 'checked'; ?> /></td>
        <!-- add as many td's here as you like -->
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Here's an alternative way to "flip" the layout.

```
<?php
    $a = array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","s","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z");
    $b = array("A","C","G","L","O","P","R","X","Z");
?>
<table>
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) : ?>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($a as $k => $v) : ?>
        <td><?php echo $v; ?><input type="checkbox" name="system[]" value="<?php echo $v; ?>" <?php if (in_array($v, $b)) echo 'checked'; ?> /></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endfor; ?>
</table>
```

After our discussion in chat I have the code you're looking for:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <?php for($i = 1; $i < count($a); $i++) : $j = $i-1; ?>
        <td><?php echo $a[$j]; ?><input type="checkbox" name="system[]" value="<?php echo $a[$j]; ?>" <?php if (in_array($a[$j], $b)) echo 'checked'; ?> /></td>
        <?php if($i % 3 === 0) echo '</tr><tr>'; ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: smart coding! i like it.But it shows in single column. how can i make them into 3 columns?

Comment: @Newbie just add more `<td></td>` where it says this `<!-- add as many td's here as you like -->` :)

Comment: +1 for the use of the alternate syntax alone.

Comment: @Newbie Do you mean 3 rows?

Comment: Not 3 rows, but 3 columns. Then it will be 9 rows 3 columns, with 2 records (Y and Z) in the 9th row.

Comment: @Newbie See the update, hope that helps

Comment: it becomes 3 rows 26 columns :from A to Z now.

Comment: @Newbie Just for future reference.. rows go across columns go up and down :)

Comment: Is it possible to make it row 1 ABC ;row 2 DEF;row 3 GHI; ... in this way?

Comment: @Newbie it certainly is though I can't see a good reason to cram three things into one td?

Comment: Sorry again.  I mean A,B,C in one row but 3 different columns.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20790/discussion-between-newbie-and-dale)

Comment: @Newbie Please see last update, that's what your looking for :D

Comment: hi Dale, the "Z" is missing somehow. Im still studying your code, it looks complicated for me @.@

Comment: @Dale, i got it now! it should be " $i <= count($a); ", now it works!~ thanks for your help~ ;D